# How to submit textbox value instead of "Other" to database

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following html code is part of a form, which sends the information to a java servlet and updates sql database. It is a dropdown menu. When the user selects "Other", javascript makes a textbox appear so that the user can specify more detail. However, when user presses submit button, in the database, it simply says "Other" instead of what the user entered in the text box. Help is appreciated, thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showfield(name){
        if (name == 'Other')
            document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = 'Please Specify: <input type="text" name="other" />';
        else 
            document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = '';
    }
</script>

<select id="description" name="description" onchange="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)" required>
    <option disabled selected value> ---Select--- </option>
    <option value="Accommodation">Accommodation</option>
    <option value="Travel">Travel</option>
    <option value="Meal Allowanced">Meal Allowances</option>
    <option value="Flat Rate">Flat Rate Expenses</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
<div id="div1"></div>
```

Comment: Give the `input` you append the same `name` as the select. The value will then be sent to the server as `Other,[input value here...]`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan 

Hi, thanks! But I didn't quite get it.

'<input type="text" name="other" />';' what should i replace "other" with?

Comment: Something like this works too: https://jsfiddle.net/66hhwng4/

Comment: @javaprogrammer `<input type="text" name="description" />`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I tried that, made no difference unfortunately :/ value is still saying "Other"

Comment: @Hackerman Still no difference.

Comment: If you really know what is happening in the background, then you should realize that with that code, the value of the selected option get changed from `Other` to the value entered in the textbox...just use the html inspector(F12)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the field you're checking on the server is "description" which is the name of your `select`. Which is indeed set to "Other" (this is the value of the selected `option`).

I would have written it a bit differently but with the current code you need to name the `input` with some other name and check that one on your server, or change the selected `option` value.

Example change for client code:

```
<select id="description" name="description" required>
    <option disabled selected value> ---Select--- </option>
    <option value="Accommodation">Accommodation</option>
    <option value="Travel">Travel</option>
    <option value="Meal Allowanced">Meal Allowances</option>
    <option value="Flat Rate">Flat Rate Expenses</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
<div id="div1">
    Please Specify: <input type="text" name="otherDescription" />
</div>

<script>
document.querySelector('#description').addEventListener('change', function (evt) {
    var inputWrapper = document.getElementById('div1'),
        input = inputWrapper.querySelector('input);
    if (evt.target.value == 'Other') {
        document.getElementById('div1').style.display = '';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'none';
        input.value = '';
    }
});
</script>
```

The you need to check 'otherDescription' on the server.

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi idan! Thanks for your feedback. How should I change the code?

Comment: I would have written the `input` field in the `div` and keep it hidden until the selection is changed.

Comment: Currently not near a computer, so can't really write an example... If it'll still be relevant when I'll be near a computer I'll add a snippet to my answer.

Comment: Added some changes.
I think it makes it a bit more readable this way. Nothing is absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all of this markup is contained within a `<form>` element that will be submitted to the server, you should be able to simply check to see if the value posted for `description` is "Other" and then read the posted value for `other`.

The code will vary depending on your server-side implementation.